# How to add "All" option on top of the Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I need to add in the "ALL" option as the top choice of a combobox. I have tried this code below but not working. Error I get is "cannot convert from '<anonymous type: string Name, int Value>' to '<anonymous type: string CountryName, int CountryId>'"
How should I do? Please I'm new to this staffs.

This is my code

```
private void LoadCountries()
        {
            try
            {
                using (Db db = new Db())
                {
                    var countries = (from u in db.Countries
                                     select new {Name =  u.CountryId, Value = u.CountryName }).ToList();


                    countries.Insert(0, new { Name = "All", Value = -1 }); // here I'am trying to add "All" Option

                    cmbCountry.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
                    cmbCountry.ValueMember = "CountryId";
                    cmbCountry.DataSource = countries;

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                Exception inner = ex.InnerException;
                while (inner != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(inner.Message);
                    inner = inner.InnerException;
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `I have tried this code below but npt working`  What's not working?  Errors?

Comment: Does any of it appear?  I wouldn't expect it to.  Your anonymous object has properties `Name` and `Value`, but you are setting display and value members to `CountryName` and `CountryId`

Comment: @Jonesopolis thank you for your response. Even if I write without properites just like "select new { u.CountryName, u.CountryId  }).ToList();" I get the same error. What Should I do ? Thank you again and appricate if you write some code so it would be esiest to me to understand. Error is "cannot convert from '<anonymous type: string Name, int Value>' to '<anonymous type: string CountryName, int CountryId>'"

Comment: @LarsTech , thank you for your response. Error I get is "cannot convert from '<anonymous type: string Name, int Value>' to '<anonymous type: string CountryName, int CountryId>'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to correctly specify the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties:

```
var countries = (from u in db.Countries
                 select new { Name =  u.CountryName, Value = u.CountryId }).ToList();

countries.Insert(0, new { Name = "All", Value = -1 }); 

cmbCountry.DisplayMember = "Name"; //use correct property name
cmbCountry.ValueMember = "Value";
cmbCountry.DataSource = countries;
```

Comment: now after updated with your code I get allmost similar error "cannot convert from '<anonymous type: string Name, int Value>' to '<anonymous type: int Name, string Value>'"

Comment: I copied your properties which were backward.  Try the update

Comment: Wonderful, it's working. Thank very much. You save my day .... Thank you again!